# GNU ld reports syntax-error when I specify an output section type as described in the official documentation

Tags: linker, ld

The official [GNU ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Attributes.html) says that I can specify an optional type for an output section:

```
section [address] [(type)] :
  [AT(lma)]
  [ALIGN(section_align) | ALIGN_WITH_INPUT]
  [SUBALIGN(subsection_align)]
  [constraint]
  {
    output-section-command
    output-section-command
    …
  } [>region] [AT>lma_region] [:phdr :phdr …] [=fillexp]
```

If I do a full-text search for the pattern `TYPE =`  in the source code of GNU ld, I find examples such as

```
SECTIONS {
  .rom  (NOLOAD)   : { LONG(1234); }
  .ro   (READONLY) : { LONG(5678); }
  .over (OVERLAY)  : { LONG(0123); }
  progbits (TYPE=SHT_PROGBITS) : { BYTE(1) }
```

(from GNU binutils @ 658ba81aef5 in `/ld/testsuite/ld-scripts/output-section-types.t`)

However, I specify the following in my linker script

```
.bss ALIGN(4K) (TYPE = SHT_PROGBITS) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(COMMON)
    *(.bss .bss.*)
}
```

`GNU ld` reports an error in this line. Without `(TYPE = SHT_PROGBITS)`, it works. Isn't this how it is supposed to work?

I'm using GNU binutils at version 2.34.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is perfectly fine. The problem is that the used `GNU ld` is outdated. The support to specify the output section type was relatively recently merged on 2022-02-16, as the [changelog](https://fossies.org/linux/binutils/ld/ChangeLog) says. It should be available since GNU binutils 2.39.